# Ruby on rails form errors not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to display errors in my form but it not appearing, could someone help me on this ?

Here is my controller :

```
def create
 @bug = Bug.create(bug_params)

 redirect_to bugs_path
end

private

  def bug_params
    params.require(:bug).permit(:owner, :title, :description)
  end
```

My model :

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord

    validates_presence_of :title
end
```

And my form :

```
<%= form_with model: @bug do |form| %>
    <% if @bug.errors.any? %>
        <h2>Errors : </h2>
        <ul>
            <% @bug.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><<%= message %>/li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>

    <% end %>

    <%= form.select :owner, @users.collect {|u| [ u.username, u.id ] } %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, placeholder: "title" %>
    <%= form.text_area :description, placeholder: "description" %>

    <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is you are redirecting to `bugs_path` irrespective of the Bug being created or not. Instead, you should do something like this

```
@bug = Bug.new(bug_params)

if @bug.save
  redirect_to bugs_path, notice: 'Bug was successfully created.'
else
  render :new
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this, but as for the solution of Sahidur, the bug is not created but I can't see the error message, do you think everything is right with my form ?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup has problems change this

`<li><<%= message %>/li>`

for

`<li><%= message %></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Your controller create method need to modify for displaying error messages. Currently Your trying to create a Bug. If Bug created or not created then you redirected to bugs index page that's error object is resetting.

Here's the modified create method code -

```
def create
 @bug = Bug.create(bug_params)

 respond_to do |format|
   if @bug.persisted?
     format.html { redirect_to bugs_path, notice: 'Bug was successfully created.' }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
   end
 end
end
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually with that code, the bug is not created but still can't see the errors messages, may I add something in my form ?

Comment: By default form_with is making Ajax request. For prevent this you should add a param to form like this -  <%= form_with model: @bug, local: true do |form |

Comment: When I add local: true, I have the error : "undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass" edit : I tried without the comma and nothing changed

Comment: I guess this issue was occurring for owner select helper code. Can you please remove form select helper and test.

Comment: I have the same result, bug is not created but errors are not displayed

Comment: Is it possible to share your repository on GitHub. Then I can inspect it.

Comment: Sure, could you check it here : https://github.com/DamienCompere/rails-project thanks

Comment: @DamienCompère I have fixed your issue and check it from https://github.com/sahidursuman/rails-project